# How to assign colors to table cells depending on their values in Spotfire

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, spotfire

## Spotfire

I created a cross table in Spotfire as below.

I want to create the same table using html in text area.
I created the table and added values using calculated values.But I have no idea how to set the background color dynamically.

> ＜TD style="HEIGHT: 21px; WIDTH: 248px; PADDING-LEFT: 20px;" bgcolor={Drop Down List value or Calculated Value}>45＜/TD＞

Color rules are as below.

Red= Production≧50

Yellow=　50＞Production≧30

Green=   Production＜40

Any Idea?

Thanks for your support in advance.[image]

Comment: The title doesn't match correctly the question.
Your are asking how to dinamically assign a color to table cells. I think a more accurate title to the post would be "How to assign colors to table cells depending on their values"

Comment: If you are creating the table manually you can just assign a class with the name of the color to every cell. And assign a color the the corresponding class via css.
If you have no idea what i mean by class or css you have to learn a few basics before starting. If you are creating the table dinamiclly (for instance, on server side via php or on client side via javascript, please let us know how you are crearing it so we can provide a more focused solution)

Comment: I suggest also to tag this question with only html, css. Spotfire has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @Santi Spotfire does have something to do with this question. The way HTML/CSS/JS works in Spotfire, while very similar to web applications, can also be different with regards to development. Spotfire should remain a tag because its being created within the Spotfire tool. Natasha, you will have to use Javascript for this in Spotfire. I have a script that I will go find but you can assign IDs to the calculated fields, then by name, pass those fields into JS where you implement this logic. You will then use `MutationObserver` to refresh anytime values change.

Comment: @MarkP. Thanks for replying.
I would be really grateful if you can share some sample script.
hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

I will share how my example is set up. It may be different from yours but should act as a guide. In my example, I have HTML boxes that need to toggle between Blue and Yellow based on the absence or presence of a negative (-) sign.

**Step one** is to set up some CSS to color it as if the data is positive (Blue):

```
.colorContainerBlue {background: #29A2EF;}
```

**Step two** is to set up my calculated values in their own div that is inside a parent "watcher" div. This will be very important later when setting up `MutationObserver()`:

```
<!-- Watch for any changes within this div using JS MutationObserver -->
<div id="watcher">
    <!-- measure 1 -->
    <div id="measure1" style="display:none">
    <SpotfireControl id="your_id_here" />
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Step three** is to then set up your HTML element that holds the value. In my case its a bunch of `flexboxes` but in your case its simply an HTML table. So in my code it looks like this:

```
<li class="colorContainerBlue valueReturnedFromJS"></li>
```

Now comes the magic. **Step four** is to set up a JS file to pull in the calculated value from step two above, look at it, change the color of the class accordingly, then pass it back out to the table, all while only running when the calculated value changes. This is achieved in my example in the following manner:

```
function refreshWidth() {
//measure1
//get values from HTML
MeasureOne = document.getElementById('measure1');
MeasureOneValue= MeasureOne.innerText;

//check for negatives and change background colors (looking for negative sign). 
if (MeasureOneValue.indexOf("-") != -1) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('colorContainerBlue')[0].style.background = "#FFDB4A";
}
else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('colorContainerBlue')[0].style.background = "#29A2EF";
}

//return value to HTML
document.getElementsByClassName('valueReturnedFromJS')[0].innerHTML = MeasureOneValue;
}

//MutationObserver to refresh when needed. Works better than running every second as that causes issues with exporting in newer versions of Spotfire
var target = document.getElementById('watcher');
var observer = new MutationObserver(refreshWidth);
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true};
observer.observe(target, config);
```

If you get all the naming correct and you get the `if else` statement correct in the JS file, this should work with some tweaking for your exact example. Without using your exact .`.dxp` file, I cannot fully customize this for you. Hopefully this helps to lay out a process to follow!

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple rows and cells to be populated with color, you can do some sample like this

```js
function refreshWidth() {

    $('#table_id td.y_n').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
            $(this).css('background-color','#f00');
        }
        else if ($(this).text() == 'Y') {
            $(this).css('background-color','green');
        }
    });
}

//MutationObserver to refresh when needed. Works better than running every second as that causes issues with exporting in newer versions of Spotfire
var target = document.getElementById('watcher');
var observer = new MutationObserver(refreshWidth);
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true};
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<div id="watcher">

<table id="table_id">
 <tr><th>Question</th><th>Y/N?</th></tr>
 <tr><td>I am me.</td><td class="y_n"><SpotfireControl id="2bb8174ce9a8465a84be2ef7c0eb2797" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>I am him.</td><td class="y_n"><SpotfireControl id="9ef686aa45d847ee98fafb94c7dfe880" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>I am not sure.</td><td class="y_n"><SpotfireControl id="e8ceaec4965c480587bbf352e46e7d2a" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>This is a table.</td><td class="y_n"><SpotfireControl id="67b9c407bef24eb888ece4875b5807c2" /></td></tr>

</table>

</div>
```